# How to split list of words into 2d array of letters?

Tags: java, arrays, string, 2d

What would be right syntax to create a 2d array `letter[x][y]` with all the letters of `String words`? x = ordinal of word and y = ordinal of letter of the word-x i.e. `letter[1][2]` would be 3rd letter of "Eraser" which is "a"

This is what I tried:

```
String words = "Pencil Eraser Scissors";
String[] separate = words.split(" ");
String[][] letters = separate.split("");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String[][] letters = separate.split("");
```

That wouldn't compile since arrays don't have a `split` method.

I would use a 2D char array to accomplish this.

```
String words = "Pencil Eraser Scissors";
String[] wordsSplitted = words.split(" ");
char[][] lettersByWord = new char[wordsSplitted.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < lettersByWord.length; i++){
    lettersByWord[i] = wordsSplitted[i].toCharArray();
}
System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(lettersByWord));
```

Prints:

```
[[P, e, n, c, i, l], [E, r, a, s, e, r], [S, c, i, s, s, o, r, s]]
```

Comment: just printing `System.out.print(lettersByWord[1][2]);` would have been more acceptable, probably.

Comment: @user3403621 This works for an arbitrary number of words you get when you split your original String by a whitespace.